# convolution with heat kernel uniformly increases convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis, stochastic-analysis, heat-equation

Let $p(x) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2}$ and let $f$ be any convex function. Some calculations have led me to believe the conjecture that
$$p * f(x) \geq \frac12 (f(x+\epsilon)+f(x-\epsilon))$$ for all $\epsilon$ up to some fixed universal positive value that is **independent** of the convex function $f$ and real number $x$. The star denotes convolution.

Some questions I have are: is it true? How large can $\epsilon$ be?

I'd be grateful for some literature on the subject as well, addressing for instance multidimensional generalizations etc.

Comment: If you only require convexity and nothing else then this is easily seen to be false, just consider $f$ which is zero on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and $1$ elsewhere. The LHS at $x=0$ will basically be $P(|X|>\epsilon)$ for some normal variable $X$ while the RHS will be just $1$. You can consider a regularization of that with sufficiently steep slope, if you don't like the discontinuity. Some other condition is necessary if you want this $\epsilon$ to not depend on $f$.

Comment: @Ian the indicator function of the complement of an interval is not a convex function, so your example does not work.

Comment: It's a nonstrictly convex function (in the sense that it lies nonstrictly below its secant lines). And as I said before, if you don't like the example, you can regularize it. The only properties you need are $f \leq 1$ everywhere, $m(\{ f<1 \})>0$, and $f(\pm \epsilon)=1$, so that the RHS is $1$ and the LHS is less than $1$. That can absolutely be achieved while assuming just convexity. I am not so sure whether it can be achieved while assuming strict convexity.

Comment: @ian it is not convex in any sense. Check the sublevels greater than 1 and you get a strip with a rectangle sticking out of the bottom. Regularizing will not help at all.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I had an erroneous picture in my head. I'm still skeptical of the idea that this $\epsilon$ can be independent of $f$. Can you elaborate some on these calculations that made you suspect this?

Comment: The calculation is just that I tried it for even powers of x and absolute value and it seems to be true. At the level of measures what I am asking is whether or not a sum of close enough dirac masses is convex-ordered by a Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer is yes and it can be deduced from the identities:

$$\frac12(f(x+\epsilon)+f(x-\epsilon)) -f(x) = \int_\Bbb R f’’(x-u)\max\{0,\epsilon-|u|\}du$$
$$p_t*f(x)-f(x) =\int_\Bbb R f’’(x-u)\bigg[ \int_0^t p_s(u)ds\bigg]du.$$
The first of these is deduced from an annoying integration by parts. In the second identity $p_t$ denotes the standard heat kernel and the identity is derived from the fact that it solves the heat equation, then using self adjointness of the second derivative and applying fubini. Note that in both identities the integral against $f’’$ may have to be interpreted in a distributional sense as $f’’$ may in general only exist as a positive measure for convex $f$.

From the identities it is clear that the first quantity above is dominated by the second quantity *uniformly over all convex functions* for precisely those pairs $(\epsilon,t)$ such that $$\max\{\epsilon-|u|,0\}\leq \int_0^t p_s(u)ds,\;\;\;\; \forall u\in \Bbb R.$$ In particular for a given $t$ the claim will be true for small enough (but strictly positive!) $\epsilon$ and conversely for a given $\epsilon$ it will be true for large enough $t$.

The optimal relationship is precisely  $t=\epsilon^2\pi/2.$ Furthermore the proof shows that the $f$ that achieves the optimal value has to be something whose second derivative is a delta function at 0, i.e., absolute value.

A final remark is that the proof may be slightly modified to consider things like $\frac13f(x+2\epsilon) +\frac23 f(x-\epsilon)$, in which case the kernel $\max\{0,\epsilon-|u|\}$ needs to be replaced by the appropriate function which will also be a triangular shape but with different slopes on each side. Then the optimal function and relation changes.